# UK Visitor visa for academic

Tags: visas, uk, applications

I am an undergraduate engineering student from a technical institute in India. I want to apply UK Visa for a two-month research internship (June-July) under a professor in the UK during my summer break. Here are some of my queries:

1. What is the type of visa I should apply for
   (from my research, it seems like UK Visitor Visa would suffice)?
2. What are the documents I would need from first the host institute in UK and Second my current institute?
3. Would I need an ATAS certificate?
4. Any other documents? (My father would sponsor my trip)

Comment: Is that a paid internship?

Comment: Has the institution where you will be studying provided any guidance? Generally they know what forms need to be filled out.

Answer (score 3):

The [study page](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor/visit-to-study) on the UK standard visitor visa page states :

> ### If you’re visiting to do a short piece of research
>
> #### You must prove that:
>
> - you’re at least 16 years old
> - you’re already enrolled on a course overseas that is the equivalent of a UK degree
> - you’ve been accepted by a UK higher education institution to take part in research that’s relevant to the course you’re studying
>   overseas
>
> You can visit for up to 6 months to do your research.
>
> Documents you must provide
>
> You’ll need to provide confirmation from your overseas course provider
> that the research or research tuition is part of, or relevant to, the
> course you’re doing overseas.

Comment: Hello, while filling out the visa application, selecting the visit to study option takes me to the course enrollment page (that is study at an accredited institution. Do you know where can I get this option (visiting to do a short piece of research)?